# Creating a Custom Field Type for Fieldable Entities

Tags: entities

**Problem**

My custom field type will not save data. Every time I save the entity it is attached to (it doesn't matter what entity I do this on) the value always comes out NULL and SQL throws an error because that field can not be NULL in the database.

**Research**

I'm currently working on a module that will provide a custom field type to be used on entities. I have done my best from looking at the docs for [Field Types API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/group/field_types/7) and seeing how other modules have implemented this e.g. Entity Reference, Examples, and Address Field.

**Attempt**

Below is my attempt and can not figure out what is wrong with the code.

**.install file**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_schema().
 */
function civsearch_code_reference_field_schema($field) {
  $columns = array(
    'target_id' => array(
      'description' => 'The id of the target code.',
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
  );

  return array(
    'columns' => $columns,
    'indexes' => array(
      'target_id' => array('target_id'),
    ),
  );
}
```

**.module file**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_info().
 */
function civsearch_code_reference_field_info() {
  return array(
    'civsearch_code_reference' => array(
      'label' => t('Code Reference'),
      'description' => t('This field stores the target_id of the referenced code.'),
      'settings' => array(
        'code_type' => '',
      ),
      'instance_settings' => array(),
      'default_widget' => 'civsearch_code_reference_autocomplete_tags',
      'default_formatter' => 'civsearch_code_reference_label',
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_settings_form().
 */
function civsearch_code_reference_field_settings_form($field, $instance, $has_data) {
  $settings = $field['settings'];

  $options = array(
    'muni_cloud_bulk' => t('Bulk'),
    'muni_cloud_bulk_exception' => t('Bulk Exception'),
    'muni_cloud_bulk_zoning_district' => t('Bulk Zoning District'),
    'muni_cloud_exception' => t('Exception'),
    'muni_cloud_jurisdiction' => t('Jurisdiction'),
    'muni_cloud_use' => t('Use'),
    'muni_cloud_use_unit' => t('Use Unit'),
    'muni_cloud_use_regulation' => t('Use Regulation'),
    'muni_cloud_use_zoning_district' => t('Use Zoning District'),
    'muni_cloud_zoning_category' => t('Zoning Category'),
    'muni_cloud_zoning_district' => t('Zoning District'),
  );

  $form['code_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Code Type'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#description' => t('The code type to be referenced.'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['code_type'],
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_info().
 */
function civsearch_code_reference_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'civsearch_code_reference_autocomplete_tags' => array(
      'label' => t('Autocomplete (Tags style)'),
      'description' => t('An autocomplete text field.'),
      'field types' => array('civsearch_code_reference'),
      'settings' => array(
        'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
        'size' => 60,
        'path' => '',
      ),
      'behaviors' => array(
        'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_CUSTOM,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_settings_form().
 */
function civsearch_code_reference_field_widget_settings_form($field, $instance) {
  $widget = $instance['widget'];
  $settings = $widget['settings'];

  $form = array();

  $form['match_operator'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Autocomplete matching'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['match_operator'],
    '#options' => array(
      'STARTS_WITH' => t('Starts with'),
      'CONTAINS' => t('Contains'),
    ),
    '#description' => t('Select the method used to collect autocomplete suggestions.'),
  );
  $form['size'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Size of textfield'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['size'],
    '#element_validate' => array('_element_validate_integer_positive'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form().
 */
function civsearch_code_reference_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

  $element += array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#maxlength' => 1024,
    '#defaul_value' => 'bob',
    '#size' => $instance['widget']['settings']['size'],
  );

  return array('target_id' => $element);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function civsearch_code_reference_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    'civsearch_code_reference_label' => array(
      'label' => t('Label'),
      'description' => t('Display the label of the referenced codes.'),
      'field types' => array('civsearch_code_reference'),
      'settings' => array(
        'link' => FALSE,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_settings_form().
 */
function civsearch_code_reference_field_formatter_settings_form($field, $instance, $view_mode, $form, &$form_state) {
  $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
  $settings = $display['settings'];

  $element = array();

  if ($display['type'] == 'civsearch_code_reference_label') {
    $element['link'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Link label to the referenced code.'),
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => $settings['link'],
    );
  }

  return $element;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_settings_summary().
 */
function civsearch_code_reference_field_formatter_settings_summary($field, $instance, $view_mode) {
  $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
  $settings = $display['settings'];

  $summary = array();

  if ($display['type'] == 'civsearch_code_reference_label') {
    $summary[] = $settings['link'] ? t('Link to the referenced code') : t('No link');
  }

  return implode('<br />', $summary);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_is_empty().
 */
function civsearch_code_reference_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
  return empty($item);
}
```

**Error**

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
'field_jurisdiction_target_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO 
{field_data_field_jurisdiction} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle,
delta, language, field_jurisdiction_target_id) VALUES
(:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
:db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, 
:db_insert_placeholder_6); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 
civsearch_property [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 17 [:db_insert_placeholder_2]
=> 17 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => test [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 
[:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => ) in 
field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 452 of
/var/dev/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module)
```

**Debug Backtrace**

```
15: field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (Array, 2 elements)
14: call_user_func_array() (Array, 1 element)
13: module_invoke() (Array, 2 elements)
12: field_attach_insert() (Array, 2 elements)
11: EntityAPIController->invoke() (Array, 2 elements)
10: EntityAPIController->save() (Array, 2 elements)
 9: Entity->save() (Array, 2 elements)
 8: civsearch_property_edit_form_submit() (Array, 2 elements)
 7: form_execute_handlers() (Array, 2 elements)
 6: drupal_process_form() (Array, 2 elements)
 5: drupal_build_form() (Array, 2 elements)
 4: drupal_get_form() (Array, 2 elements)
 3: civsearch_property_form_wrapper() (Array, 2 elements)
 2: call_user_func_array() (Array, 1 element)
 1: menu_execute_active_handler() (Array, 2 elements)
 0: main() (Array, 2 elements)
```

Comment: Show debug_backtrace() stack from place where error occours please. And error message of course.

Comment: Sorry error message was too long for a comment here. Here is a link to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nedsiHL4).

Comment: As far as the backtrace goes, I'm not sure how to get this information to you as it is way to long for even pastebin.

Comment: Put error message in post, just edit it. From backtrace I need functions names only.

Comment: Alright the SQL error and the debug_backtrace function names are added to original message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form().
 */
function civsearch_code_reference_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  $value = isset($items[$delta]['target_id']) ? $items[$delta]['target_id'] : '';

  $element += array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#maxlength' => 1024,
    '#default_value' => $value,
    '#size' => $instance['widget']['settings']['size'],
  );

  // There are array wrapper because if it is no then value will be cut to one letter.
  // Link to realted toric is under the code block.
  return array(array('target_id' => $element));
}
```

[Letter cutting](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20559/custom-widget-field-only-saves-first-letter-disappears-on-edit).. Second array wrap is because of this FIELD_BEHAVIOR_CUSTOM, for default type one time is enough. Also, you have text mistake in code `'#defaul_value' => 'bob'`, there is no 't' at the 'defaul' end, and this value must be integer.

Comment: Still getting the same error. From my understanding it needs to be target_id because that is the column in the field table I am saving the submitted data to.

Comment: @FatGuyLaughing, I edited the answer, checked this code localy it works. I thought drupal adds validation by itself but It don't.

Comment: Thanks! this worked. I'll have to look into why I entityreference field isn't double wrapping even though it uses the same custom behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified that `target_id` is `not null` in `hook_field_schema`, therefore and you're actually passing NULL as per `db_insert_placeholder_6`, it won't let you save the field.

So either this line :

```
'not null' => TRUE,
```

needs to be removed (field instance needs to be recreated) or make sure the value is not empty

This line is invalid as per typo:

```
'#defaul_value' => 'bob',
```

so it should be:

```
'#default_value' => 'bob',
```

That's probably the main reason.